# Repeat blink sketch for a specified time

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno, arduino-ide

I need help with an Arduino sketch , I want to repeat the blink sketch for a specified amount of time (3minutes for example) , then Stop .
As we know , the loop() keeps runing forever which is not what I want . Any ideas how I can achieve this , blinking an LED for X minutes and Stopping ?

Comment: well, you can add, in the loop, `if (millis() > 180000) while(1);`. So if 180 seconds (= 3 minutes) have passed since the start of the program, it halts until a reset occurs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably make use of some timer library. A simple (maybe naive) way to achieve what you want to do is to make use of a boolean that is set to 0 when 3 minutes has passed or simply digitalWrite the led to low when the timer has passed.

Check this link:
http://playground.arduino.cc/Code/Timer

I suggest that you use `int after(long duration, callback)`.

Below is a (very) simple example of how you probably could do:

```
#include "Timer.h"
Timer t;
LED = 1;

void setup() {
   int afterTime = t.after(180000, cancelLED);
}

void loop() {
   t.update();
   if(LED) {
      //The "write HIGH" statement in your sketch here.
   }
   else {
      //Write the led to LOW
   }
}

void cancelLED() {
   LED = 0;
}
```

I haven't used the library myself, I just checked the the docs and wrote an example to give you some ideas. Don't expect it to work right away.